# When does HTTPS handshake take place?

Tags: https

I understand from various sources that the HTTPS handshake is the heaviest part of using HTTPS. I'm using POSTs internally between my servers to communicate information and would like to use HTTPS for it. I wondered how long the actual HTTPS handshake lasts/"stays open"? Is it re-done for each POST I'm sending to a server, or what is the lifetime?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The SSL handshake is only done at the beginning of a session and is mainly about generating a shared session key that is used to encrypt all later traffic.

You can find a very good description of the handshake [here](http://www.moserware.com/2009/06/first-few-milliseconds-of-https.html).

Answer (score 2):

I believe the handshake occurs on connection (ie, as part of the SSL negotiation). It you use HTTP keep-alive connections then the handshake only occurs once as long as the connection is active.

Comment: Does using HTTP keep-alive for HTTPS reduce security?

Comment: and if there isn't any keep-alive, is the SSL handshake repeated on top of each new TCP connection?

Comment: No and no. There is an abbreviated handshake via which the peers can resume a previous session.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the particulars, but I'm sure the handshake is supposed to occur only when the session is started. It would be too expensive otherwise.

Edit: Here's a nice [description of the process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#TLS_handshake_in_detail).