# Calling secure connection using HttpConnection class - Java ME/Blackberry

Tags: http, blackberry, https, java-me

I'm using HttpConnection class for service calls. But, when I tried HTTPS (secure) connections using the same class, it's working fine; but taking more time.

```
((HttpConnection)Connector.open(url, 3, true));
```

Is it really secure to make https calls using this HttpConnection ? 
Can this be a reason for it to take more time ?

Comment: You need to read the classes that describe `Connector`, `HttpConnection` and `HttpsConncton` and understand the relation between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @adwiv suggested, take a look at the documentation for [HttpConnection](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/javax/microedition/io/HttpConnection.html) and [HttpsConnection](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/javax/microedition/io/HttpsConnection.html).  As you'll see, an `HttpsConnection` **is a** `HttpConnection` (it extends the `HttpConnection` interface).

So, it's perfectly acceptable to cast the result of `Connector.open("https://abc.com", 3, true)` to an `HttpConnection`.  There's simply one method in the `HttpsConnection` interface that you won't have access to if you cast that way.

Take a look also [at these BlackBerry docs for HTTPS connections](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/BlackBerry-Support-for-HTTPS-connection/ta-p/445952), complete with sample code.

Regarding the **time**, it's not uncommon for HTTPS calls to be slower than HTTP calls.  Remember, both the client and server side need to encrypt or decrypt the data, and that takes time to do.  And, as noted in Peter's comment below, there is [initial handshaking that further slows down the transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4374512/119114).

And, yes, it is *secure* to use the code as you are.  If `url` is an HTTPS URL, then you'll be using a secure connection, even if you've cast it to a plain `HttpConnection`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply mate :-). The answer I was looking for was regarding the security of such calls.

Comment: Some useful info - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9960998/using-httpurlconnection-and-httpsurlconnection-to-connect-to-an-https

Comment: @Krishna, yes, if the URL starts with `https://`, then the code you show will use a secure connection, even if you cast to `HttpConnection`.

Comment: @Krishna, well, that link you posted is for an **Android** question, but in this case, the *general* idea applies to BlackBerry as well.

Comment: The main reason this takes significantly longer is that, at <connector>.open(..) time, the BlackBerry communicates with the Server to exchange credentials.  For normal http communication, there is only one connection and this doesn't happen until there is some data required at the BlackBerry end, such as the http response code.  But for https, there is at least 1 round trip and perhaps more at open time, in addition to the communication performed when processing the actual http request.  So network latency is the main reason an https:// connection takes longer than an http:// connection.